# D3 animation cause a high CPU usage / crash on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js

I used `D3.js` to create a customizable gauge object.

Recently, I realized that sometimes during the animation of the gauge, my CPU usage **reach 100%** and never go down, which force me to kill the tab.

This problem occurs randomly, and I have not figured out what could be the cause of this CPU usage. I have the feeling that it could be a Chrome regression because these crashs have started a few times after updating to Chrome 63, and the animations are working perfectly on **Firefox / Edge / Safari**.

This is a picture of the loaded dashboard:

[image]

This is a picture of the performance analyzer + the dashboard which is stuck until I kill the tab:

[image]

To animate the paths of the gauge, I use these functions :

```
// - in the draw method
this.p_path_filled.transition()
.duration(750)
.attrTween("d", arc_tween_filled.bind(this, this.arc_test, this.p_gauge_angle));

this.p_path_empty.transition()
.duration(750)
.attrTween("d", arc_tween_empty.bind(this, this.arc_test, this.p_gauge_angle));

// - functions which update the arc paths
function arc_tween_filled (arc_test, gauge_angle, end_slice){
    // de.deg_to_rad convert an angle from radian to degree
    var start_slice = {
        startAngle: de.deg_to_rad(((0-gauge_angle)/2)%360),
        endAngle: de.deg_to_rad(((0-gauge_angle)/2)%360)
    };

    // d is a float which interpolate from 0 to 1 and is used to update the arc patj
    return function (d){
        var obj = {
            startAngle: start_slice.startAngle,
      endAngle: start_slice.endAngle + ((end_slice.endAngle - start_slice.endAngle) * d)
        };

        // - arc_test is an arc generator (d3.svg.arc)   
        return arc_test(obj);
    };
}

function arc_tween_empty (arc_test, gauge_angle, end_slice){
    var start_slice = {
        startAngle: de.deg_to_rad(((0-gauge_angle)/2)%360),
    endAngle: -de.deg_to_rad(((0-gauge_angle)/2)%360)
    };

    return function (d){
        var obj = {
            startAngle: start_slice.startAngle + ((end_slice.startAngle - start_slice.startAngle) * d),
      endAngle: end_slice.endAngle
        };

        return arc_test(obj);
    };
}
```

If anybody have encountered a similar issue and have resolved it, I would be pleased to have his advices.

**EDIT 22/05/2018 :** It seems that everything works again on Chromium 68.

Comment: Have you found any reason for this behaviour? I think I am seeing the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have just disabled the animation because i have spend too much time on this bug. Are you facing the same problem with the attrTween() method or with another function ?

Comment: Hell yeah! I faced it too exactly with the arcTween() method... :(

Comment: You should try to increase the difference between the [startAngle and the endAngle](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/v1.3.4/README.md#arc_startAngle) of your arc at the beginning of the animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running Chromium 66 in the Visual Studio debugger, I get the following call stack.

[image: call stack]

As you can see, it seems that chromium was stuck in a method from a Tessellator class. At the start of the animation, the filled my path had a very small angle (and area) which was probably the cause of the crash. Since I have slightly increase that angle at the beginning of the animation, i havn't experienced any crash.